# Flutter как сделать нижий border с закруглением с невидимыми другими сторонами рамки

Tags: flutter, dart

По дизайну нужно сделать закругление нижней рамки у шапки с невидимыми другими сторонами рамки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на изображении, внизу шапки тонкая закруглённая линия рамки.
Проблема, с которой я столкнулся - Если задавать у контейнера borderRadius и пытаться скрыть какие-либо из сторон border'а, то получаем ошибку, `boxDecoration` умеет закруглять рамки только если все стороны `border'а` одного цвета, одной толщины и у него `style solid`

```
    return Container(
      width: size.width,
      height: size.height * 0.3,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: theme.backgroundColor,
        border: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(color: theme.primaryColor, width: 2),
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(25),
        ),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Image.asset('assets/screens/a/images/header.png',
            fit: BoxFit.fill),
      ),
    );
```

Текст ошибки:

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during paint():
A borderRadius can only be given for a uniform Border.

The following is not uniform:
BorderSide.color
BorderSide.width
BorderSide.style
```

Погуглил эту тему, рекомендовали костыли из дополнительных виджетов, но нормального ответа не нашёл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Придумал следующее решение. Вместо `border` у контейнера использовать тень.

```
    return Container(
      width: size.width,
      height: size.height * 0.3,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: theme.backgroundColor,
        boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
          new BoxShadow(
            color: theme.primaryColor,
            offset: Offset(0, 1),
          ),
        ],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Image.asset('assets/screens/a/images/header.png',
            fit: BoxFit.fill),
      ),
    );
```

Результат меня удовлетворил
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]